# How to bind a ModelExpression to a ViewComponent in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I would like to bind a model expression (such as a property) to a view component—much like I would with an HTML helper (e.g., `@Html.EditorFor()`) or a tag helper (e.g., `<partial for />`)—*and* reuse this model in the view with nested HTML and/or tag helpers. I am able to define a `ModelExpression` as a parameter on a view component, and retrieve a lot of useful metadata from it. Beyond this, I start running into roadblocks:

- How do I relay and bind to the underlying source model to e.g. an `asp-for` tag helper?
- How do I ensure property metadata (e.g. validation attributes) from `ViewData.ModelMetadata` are honored?
- How do I assemble a *fully qualified* `HtmlFieldPrefix` for the field `name` attribute?

I've provided a (simplified) scenario with code and outcomes below—but the code exposes more unknowns than answers. Much of the code is known to be incorrect, but I'm including it so we can have a concrete baseline to evaluate and discuss alternatives to.

## Scenario

The values of a `<select>` list need to be populated via a data repository. Assume it is impractical or undesirable to populate the possible values as part of e.g. the original view model (see "Alternate Options" below).

## Sample Code

#### `/Components/SelectListViewComponent.cs`

```cs
using system;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

public class SelectViewComponent 
{

  private readonly IRepository _repository;

  public SelectViewComponent(IRepository repository) 
  {
    _repository = repository?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
  }

  public IViewComponentResult Invoke(ModelExpression aspFor) 
  {
    var sourceList = _repository.Get($"{aspFor.Metadata.Name}Model");
    var model = new SelectViewModel() 
    {
      Options = new SelectList(sourceList, "Id", "Name")
    };
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(modelMetadata.Name);
    return View(model);
  }

}
```

**Notes**

- Using `ModelExpression` not only allows me to call the view component with a model expression, but also gives me a lot of useful metadata via reflection such as validation parameters.
- The parameter name `for` is illegal in C#, since it's a reserved keyword. As such, I'm instead using `aspFor`, which will be exposed to the tag helper format as `asp-for`. This is a bit of a hack, but yields a familiar interface for developers.
- Obviously, the `_repository` code and logic will vary considerably with implementation. In my own use case, I actually pull the arguments from some custom attributes.
- The `GetFullHtmlFieldName()` doesn't construct a *full* HTML field name; it always returns whatever value I submit to it, which is just the model expression name. More on this under "Issues" below.

#### `/Models/SelectViewModel.cs`

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

public class SelectViewModel {
  public SelectList Options { get; set; }
}
```

**Notes**

- Technically, in this case, I *could* just return the `SelectList` directly to the view, since it will handle the current value. However, if you bind your model to your `<select>`'s `asp-for` tag helper, then it will automatically enable `multiple`, which is the default behavior when binding to a collection model.

#### `/Views/Shared/Select/Default.cshtml`

```cs
@model SelectViewModel

<select asp-for=@Model asp-items="Model.Options">
  <option value="">Select one…</option>
</select>
```

**Notes**

- Technically, the value for `@Model` will return `SelectViewModel`. If this were an `<input />` that would be obvious. This issue is obscured due to the `SelectList` identifying the correct value, presumably from the `ViewData.ModelMetadata`.
- I could instead set the `aspFor.Model` to e.g. an `UnderlyingModel` property on the `SelectViewModel`. That would result in an HTML field name of `{HtmlFieldPrefix}.UnderlyingModel`—and would still fail to retrieve any of the metadata (such as validation attributes) from the original property.

## Variations

If I don't set the `HtmlFieldPrefix`, and place the view component within the context of e.g. a `<partial for />` or `@Html.EditorFor()` then the field names will be correct, as the `HtmlFieldPrefix` is getting defined in a parent context. If I place it directly in a top-level view, however, I will get the following error due to the `HtmlFieldPrefix` not being defined:

> ArgumentException: The name of an HTML field cannot be null or empty. Instead use methods Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper.Editor or Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper``1.EditorFor with a non-empty htmlFieldName argument value. (Parameter 'expression')

## Issues

- The `HtmlFieldPrefix` doesn't get properly populated with a fully qualified value. E.g., if the model property name is `Country` it will always return `Country`, even if the actual model path is, say, `ShippingAddress.Country` or `Addresses[2].Country`.
- The **jQuery Validation Unobtrusive** functionality isn't firing. For instance, if the property this is bound to is marked as `[Required]` then that's not getting flagged here. That's presumably because it's being bound to the `SelectViewModel`, not the parent property.
- The original model isn't being relayed in any way to the view component's view; the `SelectList` is able to infer the original value from `ViewData`, but that is lost to the view. I could relay the `aspFor.Model` via the view model, but it won't have access to the original metadata (such as validation attributes).

## Alternate Options

Some other options I've considered, and rejected for my use cases.

- **Tag Helpers:** This is easy to achieve via tag helpers. Injecting dependencies, such as a repository, into a tag helper is less elegant since there isn't a way to instantiate a tag helper via the composition root, as one can do with e.g. `IViewComponentActivator`.
- **Controllers:** In this simplified example, it is also possible to define the source collection on the top-level view model, next to the actual property (e.g., `Country` for the value, `CountryList` for the options). That may not be practical or elegant in more sophisticated examples.
- **AJAX:** The values could be retrieved via a JavaScript call to a web service, binding the JSON output to the `<select>` element on the client. I use this approach in other applications, but it's undesirable here since I don't want to expose the full range of potential query logic to a public interface.
- **Explicit Values:** I could explicitly relay the *parent* model along with the `ModelExpression` in order to recreate the parent context under the view component. That's a bit of a kludge, so I'd like to game out the `ModelExpression` approach first.

## Previous Research

This question has been asked (and answered) before:

- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855758/custom-viewcomponent-with-asp-for-as-parameter).
- [forums.ASP.net](https://forums.asp.net/t/2148104.aspx).

In both cases, however, the accepted answer (one by the OP) doesn't fully explore the question, and instead decides that a tag helper is more suitable for their scenarios. Tag helpers are great, and have their purpose; I'd like to fully explore the original questions, however, for the scenarios where view components are more appropriate (such as depending on an external service).

Am I chasing a rabbit down a hole? Or are there options that the community's deeper understanding of model expressions can resolve?

Answer (score 8):

To answer my own question in the negative: I ultimately came to the conclusion that while this may well be intuitive and desirable functionality in terms of our *parent views*, it's ultimately a confused concept in terms of our *view components*.

Even if you resolve the technical issue with extracting the fully-qualified `HtmlFieldPrefix` from `ModelExpression`, the deeper issue is conceptual. Presumably, the view component will assemble additional data, and relay it down to the view via a new view model—e.g., the `SelectViewModel` proposed in the question. Otherwise, there's no real benefit to using a view component. **In the view component's view, however, there's no logical way to map properties of the *child* view model back to the *parent* view model.**

So, for example, let us say that in your *parent view* you bind the view component to a `UserViewModel.Country` property:

```
@model UserViewModel

<vc:select asp-for="Country" />
```

Then, what properties do you bind to in the *child view*?

```cs
@model SelectViewModel

<select asp-for=@??? asp-items="Model.Options">
  <option value="">Select one…</option>
</select>
```

In my original question, I proposed `@Model`, which is similar to what you would do in e.g. an *editor template* called via `@Html.EditorFor()`:

```cs
<select asp-for=@Model asp-items="Model.Options">
  <option value="">Select one…</option>
</select>
```

That might return the correct `id` and `name` attributes, since it's falling back to the `HtmlFieldPrefix` of the `ViewData`. But, it's not going to have access to any e.g. data validation attributes, since it's binding to a `SelectViewModel` and not a reference to the original `UserViewModel.Country` property, as it would in an *editor template*.

Similarly, you could relay the `ModelExpression.Model` down via e.g. a `SelectViewModel.Model` property…

```cs
<select asp-for=@Model asp-items="Model.Options">
  <option value="">Select one…</option>
</select>
```

…but that doesn't solve the problem either since, obviously, relaying a *value* doesn't relay the *attributes* of the source property.

Ultimately, what you want is to bind your `asp-for` to the original property on the original object that your `ModelExpression` is resolving to. And while you can get metadata from `ModelExpression` *describing* that property and object, there doesn't seem to be a way to relay a *reference* to it in a way that the `asp-for` tag helpers recognize.

Obviously, one could conceive of Microsoft building in lower-level tooling into `ModelExpression` and the core implementations of the `asp-for` tag helpers which allow relaying `ModelExpression` objects all the way down the line. Alternatively, they might establish a keyword—such as `@ParentModel`—which allows a reference to the model from the *parent view*. In absence of that, however, this doesn't seem feasible.

I'm not going to mark this as the answer in hopes that someone, at some point, finds something I'm missing. I wanted to leave these notes here, however, in case anyone else is trying to make this work, and to document my own conclusions.

Comment: I'm running into the same issues. So the kind of view componentization that you can do really easily in Angular, React, Vue, how do you do that in Razor? It seems that all the UI reuse patterns, basically partials and ViewComponents run into the same issue of tag helpers binding to ModelExpressions not having access to the attrbutes that make that useful. It's starting to feel as if there isn't actually a useful UI reuse mechanism in Razor at all!