# Unobtrusive validation doesn't work with ViewComponents

Tags: asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm implementing a form with ASP.NET Core v3.1.

I have code for a drop-down on a Razor page which looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="MySelectedItem" class="m-b-none"></label>
    <help-text asp-for="MySelectedItem"></help-text>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select asp-for="MySelectedItem" asp-items="@Model.MyItems" class="form-control"></select>
        <partial name="_ValidationIcon" />
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="MySelectedItem" class="validation-message"></span>
</div>
```

In my model class, I've included a validation rule to ensure that a valid option must be selected. This renders nicely:

[image]

Now, I want to genericise this as a View Component so that I don't have to paste this lump of code anytime I want a drop-down. Here is my implementation:

```cs
public class DropdownViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

    public ModelExpression SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(ModelExpression selectedItem, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items)
    {
        Items = items;
        SelectedItem = selectedItem;
        return View(this);
    }
}
```

**/Dropdown/Default.cshtml**

```
@model Web.ViewComponents.DropdownViewComponent

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SelectedItem" class="m-b-none"></label>
    <help-text asp-for="SelectedItem"></help-text>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select asp-for="SelectedItem" asp-items="@Model.Items" class="form-control"></select>
        <partial name="_ValidationIcon" />
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="SelectedItem" class="validation-message"></span>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<vc:dropdown selected-item="MySelectedItem" items="Model.MyItems"></vc:dropdown>
```

This code correctly renders the drop-down, but the validation attributes are missing from the rendered HTML. Why?

[image]

I'm also not sure how to get the `DisplayName` from the model expression that I passed to the View Component.

Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, your validation attributes are on the `MyItems` property of your *parent* model, which isn't listed here. E.g.,

```cs
public class ParentModel {
  [Required]
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyItems { get; set; }
}
```

As such, the issue is that your view is no longer binding to that model or its `MyItems` property. Instead, it's binding to the `Items` property on the `DropdownViewComponent` model, which doesn't have any validation attributes on it. Those two properties may both be pointing to the same `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` *object reference*, but their *metadata* is entirely different. As such, ASP.NET Core is *correctly* displaying the validation attributes associated with the `DropdownViewComponent.Items` property.

I see this as an unfortunate limitation of view components—but one that's conceptually difficult to reason out of. For more information, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59507419/3025856) to a similar question I previously posed, [How to bind a `ModelExpression` to a `ViewComponent` in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963949/how-to-bind-a-modelexpression-to-a-viewcomponent-in-asp-net-core).

That said, given your particular requirements, you can work around this by passing the model which *contains* the target property to your view component—instead of passing the *value* of the target property itself—and then relaying *that* via your view component's view model:

```cs
public class DropdownViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public ParentModel ParentModel { get; set; }

    public ModelExpression SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(ModelExpression selectedItem, ParentModel model)
    {
        ParentModel = model;
        SelectedItem = selectedItem;
        return View(this);
    }
}
```

> *Note:* I would typically create a separate, lightweight view model for your view component, instead of passing your view component object down to its view. But I'm maintaining this structure for consistency with your original code.

You would then be able to bind to the original property in your view component's view, thus maintaining all of the original validation attributes:

```cs
<select asp-for="SelectedItem" asp-items="@Model.ParentModel.MyItems"></select>
```

On first approximation, this doesn't buy you much—and may even defeat your entire reason for pursuing a view component in the first place—as it forces you to operate against a single model. If multiple views with different models want to use this view component, that introduces some problems. You can mitigate these, however, by introducing a layer of abstraction.

There are a few approaches to this, such as establishing an interface, but the one I recommend is to develop a specialized list class which you use to model `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`:

```cs
public class DropdownList: List<SelectListItem> {
  public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; } = this;
}
```

And then working off of that in your `DropdownViewComponent`:

```cs
public class DropdownViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public DropdownList DropdownList { get; set; }

    public ModelExpression SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(ModelExpression selectedItem, DropdownList dropdownList)
    {
        DropdownList = dropdownList;
        SelectedItem = selectedItem;
        return View(this);
    }
}
```

And, finally, implementing it as follows in your view component's view:

```cs
<select asp-for="SelectedItem" asp-items="@Model.DropdownList.Items"></select>
```

This would allow you to override this class in order to add attributes as needed. E.g.,

```cs
public class RequiredDropdownList : DropdownList {
  [Required]
  public override Items { get; } = this;
}
```

**Note**: if you have a need to use a variety of different collections on different view models, and were relying on `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to unify them, this approach won't work. In that case, creating something like an `IDropdownList` interface makes more sense. Regardless, the concept is virtually identical.

Comment: FYI: @ciaran-gallagher: I've updated my answer to include a workaround that should satisfy your particular requirements, while keeping the explanation for why your current approach is running into problems.

Comment: Ciaran, do you happen to recall if this answer addressed your problem? If so, would you mind marking it as accepted? (If you don't recall, or if it didn't satisfy your requirements, no problem—but I figured I'd check!)